# Overriding polymer element css

Tags: polymer

I want to customize an existing polymer element [spinner-backdrop](https://customelements.io/IngressoRapidoWebComponents/spinner-backdrop/)
by overriding its z-index css attribute.

All customization attempts from the outside have failed.

Because the *z-index* attribute is not exposed for outside customization.

I'm using that component wrapped inside an Angular2 app.

Should I create an new polymer element which extends that element?

Is there a more direct route, because I have never developed an polymer element.

Comment: Have you tried setting the --spinner-backdrop-overlay mixin? [Component source code](https://github.com/IngressoRapidoWebComponents/spinner-backdrop/blob/master/spinner-backdrop.html#L84). As it appears at the end of the overlay you are able to override it with any value that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `1.0.0` release of `<spinner-backdrop>` has no CSS property/mixin to set the `z-index`, but the `--spinner-backdrop-overlay` mixin was recently added and not yet released. You'd be able to use the mixin to set the `z-index` like this:

```css
<style is="custom-style">
  spinner-backdrop {
    --spinner-backdrop-overlay: {
      z-index: 0;
    };
  }
</style>
```

If `<spinner-backdrop>` is inside a Polymer element (`<dom-module>`), your `<style>` doesn't need `is="custom-style"`. Otherwise, it's needed to apply the mixin properly.

[demo (in `<dom-module>`)](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rWmzXN?editors=1010)

[demo (in `index.html`)](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rWmGNa?editors=1000)